# How to use PERMISSION_GRANTED for same runtime permission second time from same Android activity?

Tags: android

I am asking user for read contact permission to all read contacts and show in a listview which I have done well.

Now I am trying to do like if user deny for read all contact, I will show alert dialog, if user press yes then user will redirect to PERMISSION_GRANTED for second time and if he grant permission then user will redirect to other fragment, but I face error that time. My code below:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if( grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if(InfoSetClass.getDialogCode()==0) {
                        logIn();
                        contacts();
                    }
                    else {

                        Fragment fragment=new TestFragment();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    }
                }else if( grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){

                    InfoSetClass.setDialogCode(1);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);

                    builder.setMessage("Want to select persons to invite?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context_SignUpActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SignUpActivity.this, new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
                                }, REQUEST_CODE);

                            } else {
                                // permission granted

                                Fragment fragment=new TestFragment();
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                            }

                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            logIn();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }break;

        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.systechdigital.webadeal, PID: 17825
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.systechdigital.webadeal/com.systechdigital.webadeal.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4998)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1533)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1551)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:696)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:662)
                      at com.systechdigital.webadeal.SignUpActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SignUpActivity.java:297)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7291)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7169)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4994)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: post your logcat error...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. Hope it helps.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[]
 grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            //   String permission = permissions[0];

                String permission = permissions[0];
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Fragment fragment=new TestFragment();
                    FragmentManager  
                    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                } else {

                    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {

                        // user denied WITH never ask again
                        showSettingDialog();


                    } else if (Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS.equals(permission)) {
                        showPermissionDialog();
                        // user denied WITHOUT never ask again
                        // this is a good place to explain the user
                        // why you need the permission and ask if he want
                        // to accept it (the rationale)
                    }


                }
                return;

        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Code for showPermissionDialog()

```
 private void showPermissionDialog() {

    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialog.cancel();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION);

        }
    });
    dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.setTitle("Read Contacts explaination");
    dialog.setMessage("Explaination...");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Code for showSettingDialog()

```
   private void showSettingDialog() {

    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.setTitle("Permission Denied");
    dialog.setMessage("Please enable Contacts from your app setting screen");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
public abstract int commitAllowingStateLoss ()
```

instead of `commit`..

From the Documentation:

> Like commit() but allows the commit to be executed after an activity's
>   state is saved. This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if
>   the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so this should
>   only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change
>   unexpectedly on the user.

so try this:

```
    Fragment fragment=new TestFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss ();
```

Comment: now showing this error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c007e (com.systechdigital.webadeal:id/activity_main) for fragment

but fragment working well i test that from other way.
and also its not working for if condition

Comment: Try put your container id in the layour which u want to replace